# Ace editor syntax validation worker

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor in several different modes and using it's syntax validation.

I understand the syntax is being run by a worker which does the check async. every 500 milliseconds.

I need to achieve two goals:

1. call the syntax validator on demand (such as session.$worker.makeSytnaxValidation())
2. control the value of 500 milliseconds.